# php array query

Tags: php, sql

I have the following PHP code:

```
$query = array(
    $this->userid_to,
    $userid_to,
    $this->gibid,
    $this->card_type,
    $message,
    $isDeck
);
print_r($query);   
$sql = "INSERT INTO
    cards  (
        userid_from,
        userid_to,
        gibid,
        card_type,
        message,
        isDeck,
        createdon
    ) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,current_timestamp)";
Db::execute($sql,$query);
$this->cardid=Db::getLastInsertId();
```

While running this I am  passing $message variable as blank so I am getting this error:

```
Array (
    [0] => 1
    [1] => 4
    [2] => 0
    [3] => V
    [4] => 
    [5] => N )

Fatal error: Uncaught exception
'PDOException' with message 'Database
error [23000]: Column 'message' cannot
be null, driver error code is 1048' in
/var/www/ryapi/Db.php:179 Stack trace:
0 /var/www/ryapi/Db.php(54): Db::_query('INSERT INTO car...',
    Array)
1 /var/www/ryapi/card.php(79): Db::execute('INSERT INTO car...',
    Array)
2 /var/www/ryapi/index.php(173): Card->givecard('4', NULL, NULL)
3 {main}   thrown in /var/www/ryapi/Db.php on line 179
```

If I  want to pass `$message` as blank, how can I remove this error.

Comment: Code blocks and quote blocks aren't the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure `$message` is really an empty string and not the value `NULL`.

Answer (score 1):

I think this column must not be (null). Check if you can make the column nullable.

(null) and empty string are not the same "values".

Answer (score 0):

Two solutions
- Make "message" column nullable in database, if you really expect "null" for message value. You need to be careful in doing so, if it breaks other part of application. 
- Pass dummy value like whitespace - i.e " "  OR  string like "none" or any string which will denote that there is really no message